# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. after adding new Activity

Tags: android, xml

I have been coding my app for a couple of days without any problems until I tried to add a new activity which has triggered this error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Manifest code: I never changed the code bellow other than changing the starting activity which worked fine, after that I added a new activity and that is caused the issue

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="uk.ac.abertay.contactslist">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Android Project"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I added the tools:replace="android:value" like the error suggested but this hasn't changed anything

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBkvfvE19LM1FDGhHrOkt17Kd17JX7RZDI"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

I've tried putting the tools replace line in both of the meta datas and tried having it in one or the other

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

activities

```
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactsListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SMSActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Maps2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".NewItemActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Item_listActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MyItemsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my android studio and SDK tools and that fixed it